# EComo tornar iframe "clicável" em qualquer lugar da página?

Tags: javascript, iframe, vídeo, youtube, embed

Supondo que eu tenha um vídeo do youtube em um iframe no meu site, como seria possível reproduzir o iframe clicando em qualquer lugar no corpo da página sem fazer com o que iframe tome conta da tela inteira? 
Por exemplo ao clicar em qualquer lugar da página, ou em algum outro iframe, este iframe seja executado primeiro?
Desde já, agradeço!
Estou montando um site de puzzlee e uma determinada página, como consequência da anterior, o usuário se depara com uma tela preta e terá que interagir dando apenas um clique e aguardando, para o vídeo começar. 
Já tentei fazer algo parecido com isso:

```
<a id="play-video" href="#">Reproduzir video</a><br />
<iframe id="video" width="1280" height="720" 
src="//www.youtube.com/embed/xrel=0" frameborder="0" 
allowfullscreen></iframe>


$(document).ready(function() {
$('#play-video').on('click', function(ev) {
$("#video")[0].src += "&autoplay=1";
ev.preventDefault();
 }); 
});
```

Porém não consigo extender a função de reproduzir vídeo para qualquer ponto na tela.

Comment: Coloque o código na pergunta montando um [mcve] e explique qual o objetivo de fazer isso, por favor.

Comment: Editado, amigo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se entendi corretamente a pergunta, uma opção seria você pode olhar para o evento de onClick no body, por exemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').on('click', function(ev) {
   $("#video")[0].src += "&autoplay=1";
   ev.preventDefault();
  });
 });
```

```html
<html class="" lang="en"><head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
 <title>iFrame click test</title>
  <head>
  
  </head>
 <body>
  <a id="play-video" href="#">Reproduzir video</a><br />
  <iframe 
   id="video" 
   width="1280" 
   height="720" 
   src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/SLdaFYLdsWE?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" 
   frameborder="0" 
   allow="autoplay; 
   encrypted-media" 
   allowfullscreen>
  </iframe>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Perfeito! Obrigado!

Comment: Se essa for a resposta que estava procurando, por favor marque como resposta aceita, dessa forma outros usuários que precisarem saberão qual é a solução.

Answer (score 0):

Não é possível carregar o `IFRAME` antes da própria página a não ser que essa página seja gerada dinamicamente por `Javascript`.

Sobre o IFRAME, você pode usar incorporação do vídeo assim aparentando que o vídeo está rodando diretamente do seu site com esse padrão de URL:

```
http://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO_ID
```

Exemplo:

```
<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="640" height="360"
  src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?autoplay=1&origin=http://example.com"
  frameborder="0"/>
```

Agora se você quiser usar um player costumizado vai ter que usar a API do Youtube:
[Youtube Player API Reference](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference)

Com ela você poderá criar botões com comandos JAVASCRIPT que controlem a incorporação do player podendo pausar, trocar o vídeo o tamanho, rodar uma `playlist` e para dar play.

Referente ao play somente quando a página for focada, você pode usar `onfocus`  para dar play e `onblur` pra pausar o vídeo, isso usando a API do youtube.
Fiz um exemplo com HTML5 pra entender o uso do ONFOCUS no corpo da página:

```js
var vid;
function setVideo(){
 vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
}
```

```html
<body onload="setVideo()" onfocus="vid.play();" onblur="vid.pause();">

<video id="myVideo" width="320" height="176">
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video> Clique por aqui<br />
Ou por aqui<br />Ou por aqui<br />Ou por aqui<br />Ou por aqui<br />
```

Comment: Entendi, mas qual seria a solução para, no caso, um clique no corpo da página reproduzir o iframe? mesmo que este seja carregado depois da página? No caso tirar a condição de só reproduzir o iframe ao clicar em cima dele?

Comment: Editei a postagem, desculpa, eu achei que a dificuldade fosse com o chamado do PLAY e PAUSE, entendi mal. Veja se ficou claro com o uso de ONFOCUS e ONBLUR.